# How can I select first element with a specific class

Tags: html, css

I have the following list

```
    <ul class="list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li class="foo">2</li>
        <li class="foo">3</li>
        <li class="foo">4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
```

I want to change the color of first and last `li's`, which has class `foo`, using css

```
.list .foo:first-child,
.list .foo:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

But it select nothing. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2T2yv/3/).

How can I select first and last `li's` with class `foo`. If it's not possible with css then how can I do it with jQuery.

Comment: maybe without class http://jsfiddle.net/2T2yv/7/

Comment: I want to select first `li` with class `foo`, not just first `li`

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a css selector solution for this, you can use jQuery to assign a class

```
.selected {
    color: red;
}
```

then

```
$('.list li.foo').filter(':first, :last').addClass('selected')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8cpvs/)

Comment: +1. I much prefer this to my answer. Same general idea, but much neater to do it in one line with `.filter()`.

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
$('.list li.foo').filter(':first, :last').css( "color", "red" );
```

or

```
$('.list li.foo:first,.list li.foo:last').css( "color", "red" );
```

Comment: The question states pretty clearly that only the li elements with class "Foo" should be affected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done with just CSS, but it is simple with jQuery. Here's one way:

```
var $lis = $("ul.list li.foo");
$lis.first().addClass("someClass");
$lis.last().addClass("someClass");
```

With:

```
.someClass {
    color: red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2T2yv/10/

Or a slightly different solution that doesn't repeat `.addClass()`:

```
var $lis = $("ul.list li.foo");
$lis.first().add($lis.last()).addClass("someClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.list .foo:nth-child(2n)
{
    color: green;
}
```

and Html is

```
 <ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li class="foo">2</li>
    <li class="foo">3</li>
    <li class="foo">4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2T2yv/12/)

For better understanding nth-child (pseudo-selector) you can go through this http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. @rkb wanted the first and last list item with the class of foo to be changed.

Comment: I said I want to select first and last with class `foo`. So it's second and forth `li` in this case.

Comment: What if more "foo" elements were added? Then it wouldn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/2T2yv/15/

Comment: This works in this case but what if I add one more `li` element to the end without class `foo`, your css will also make that red.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` for this:

```
$('.list li.foo').first().css('color', 'red');
$('.list li.foo').last().css('color', 'red');
```